# Switching between windows

Tags: internet-explorer, autohotkey

Backgroud: Our Call Center have special "Main" program to work in it. When incoming call it is appear "small pop-up window". Also, we have browser-style CRM. All this is running on Windows 7. When incoming call, client page in IE is loading. So, Call Center worker, to see client page, have to click in Taskbar in IE tab. When he do it, IE window shows, but "small pop-up window" is also shows above. So, goal is automatete it: worker didn't want ti click on IE.

Now code:

```
GetIeInstance()
{
  For pwb in ComObjCreate( "Shell.Application" ).Windows
   {
    If InStr(pwb.FullName, "iexplore.exe" )
    {
      Return pwb
    }
  }
  Return 0
}

ComObjError(false)

Loop
{
 ie := GetIeInstance()

 if (hran != ie.LocationURL) 
    {
    WinActivate, ahk_class IEFrame
    WinWaitActive, ahk_class IEFrame
    }

hran := ie.LocationURL

 Sleep, 100
}
```

It is clear: when we got new income call (so, new client page is loaded in IE), Windows focused on IE window. But it is not working correctly, because after a second Windows re-focused to "Main" program window (IE window "blink"). Adding

```
Winset, Alwaysontop, , ahk_class IEFrame
```

didn't help. Any idea how to fix it? (or how to emulate clicking on IE tab on Taskbar?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix It!
Adding

```
sleep, 2000
```

before

```
WinActivate, ahk_class IEFrame
```

save the world

Comment: please accept your own answer, because otherwise ppl will see your question unanswered